# Problems with angular deployment and undefined properties in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment

Hi right now I am able to add products to the db and it looks like they all have the properties I added to them in the db.  Unfortunately I am prevented from deploying for production because I am getting errors.  When I try to fix these errors so I can deploy it breaks and I cannot add items to the db.

errors preventing deployment before the 'fix':

```
ERROR in src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(10,11): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(27,13): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(48,11): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(66,11): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(10,11): : Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(27,13): : Property 'price' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(48,11): : Property 'category' does not exist on type '{}'.
src\app\admin\product-form\product-form.component.html(66,11): : Property 'imageUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

In the component if I change

```
  product = {};
```

to

```
product: Product;
```

I get

```
Error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

and if I change it to

```
product: Product = {};
```

I get

```
  ERROR in src/app/admin/product-form/product-form.component.ts(15,5): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
  Property '$key' is missing in type '{}'.
```

component:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../category.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product = {};
  id;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getAll();

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.id) {
      this.productService
        .get(this.id)
        .take(1)
        .subscribe(p => (this.product = p));
    }
  }

  save(product) {
    if (this.id) {
      this.productService.update(this.id, product);
    } else {
      this.productService.create(product);
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  delete() {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      return;
    }
    this.productService.delete(this.id);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

template:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <form #f="ngForm"
            (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input #title="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.title"
                    name="title"
                    tobject
                    ;product
                    'ype="text"
                    id="title"
                    class="form-control"
                    required>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">Title is required.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
                    </div>
                    <input #price="ngModel"
                        [(ngModel)]="product.price"
                        name="price"
                        type="number"
                        class="form-control"
                        aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"
                        required
                        [min]="0">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text">.00</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="price.touched && price.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.required">Price is required.</div>
                    <div *ngIf="price.errors.min">Price must be equal to or greater than zero.</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select #category="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.category"
                    name="category"
                    id="category"
                    class="form-control"
                    required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let c of categories$ | async"
                        [value]="c.$key">
                        {{ c.name }}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="category.touched && category.invalid">Category is required.</div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="imageUrl">Image URL</label>
                <input #imageUrl="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="product.imageUrl"
                    name="imageUrl"
                    type="text"
                    id="imageUrl"
                    class="form-control"
                    required
                    url>
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                    *ngIf="imageUrl.touched && imageUrl.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.required">Image URL is required.</div>
                    <div *ngIf="imageUrl.errors.url">Image URL must be formatted correctly.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <product-card [product]="product"
            [show-actions]="false"></product-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

product variable is defined here:

```
export interface Product {
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  category: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass default values while declaring your variable or assign default values to it inside constructor because as soon as your html is rendered it will look for the key 'title' of your variable product, which is not present at that time. Later you can assign real values to your variable product. Something like this.

```
product: Product = {
    $key: '',
    title: '',
    price: null,
    category: '',
    imageUrl: ''
};
```

I hope my answer was helpful. :)

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  I'll start always initiating my variables now!  Can't think of how it would ever hurt actually

Answer (score 2):

I would change:

```
product = {};
```

To

```
product: Product;
```

And then use the ? operator in your template to avoid undefined values being accessed:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="product?.$key">
```